# Batch create or get path in py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to create a date/time tree in neo4j as Nigel Small described [here](http://blog.nigelsmall.com/2012/09/modelling-dates-in-neo4j.html). I want to pre-populate all dates for a certain period of time, and as such, want to run multiple get_or_create_path()s in a go. However, I can't seem to find a batch version of this function, or a batch equivalent of 'run cypher query' - if I have to run them all individually, it's going to hit my runtime massively.

Is there any way to batch this process? Hopefully I'm being stupid and have just missed an obvious function! I don't mind if it's a batch version of running cypher queries, or of get_or_create_path().

Many thanks in advance,

Louis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a batch `get_or_create_path` in 1.5 but I am introducing one for 1.6. I am planning to release this on 1st October but you are welcome to try it sooner if you wish (release/1.6.0 branch on GitHub). Please bear in mind though that this release is still in development so it may change between now and release and therefore, depending on your needs, may be a bit unstable.